# Why is my code looping twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a data visualisation tool where you can input your own data. The data values are stored in an unordered list like this: `<ul><li data-name='name'><a href='#' onclick='showEditDv(this);'>Edit</a><span class='name'>name</span><span class='seperator'> | </span><span class='value'>7</span></li></ul`. There can be more than one list item in the list. When you click on the Edit button it calls the `showEditDv()` function, giving a reference to itself. Before I show the function, I will say that the `data` object is organised like this:

```
data ->
    name: "root",
    children: [ {name: "something", size: "7"},
        {name: "something-else", size: "999"} ]
```

This is the code for the function:

```
function showEditDv(object) {
    var name = $(object).parent().attr("data-name"),
        input = new Opentip($(object), {removeElementsOnHide: true, target: null, showOn: null, hideTrigger: "closeButton"}),
        disabled = (data.children[getChildIndexByName(name)].hasOwnProperty("children")) ? "disabled" : "";

    input.setContent("<label>Name:</label><input type='text' data-prevname='" + name + "' value='" + name + "' class='dv-add-name' /><label>Value:</label><input " + disabled + " type='text' class='dv-add-value' value='" + data.children[getChildIndexByName(name)].size + "' /><button class='callEditDv'>Apply</button>"); // Set content of opentip

    input.show();

    $("body").on("click", ".callEditDv", function() {
        var newname = $(this).siblings(".dv-add-name").val(),
            prevname = $(this).siblings(".dv-add-name").attr("data-prevname"),
            value = $(this).siblings(".dv-add-value").val();

        if (newname !== prevname)
        {
            data.children[ getChildIndexByName(prevname) ].name = newname; // Update name

            $(object).parent().attr("data-name", newname); // Update parent data

            $(object).siblings(".name").text(newname); // Update form
        }

        if (data.children[ getChildIndexByName(newname) ].size !== value)
        {
            data.children[ getChildIndexByName(newname) ].size = value;
            $(object).siblings(".value").text(value);
        }
        input.hide();
    });
}
```

It uses Opentip, which is just a way of creating dynamic popups / tooltips. The problem is that once you have changed a data value once, when you try to change it again it loops through the code twice! The first time everything works as expected, but the second time it does it again, using the same `prevname`, which means that `getChildIndexByName` returns `undefined` and it can't set the variable causing an error. `getChildIndexByName` loops through the values of `data.children` checking the names until it finds a match, and then returns the index of the object in the array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("body").off('click').on("click",...
```

[jQuery Documentations](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/#entry-longdesc)

> Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind().
>   (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to
>   attach and remove event handlers on elements.)

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$("body").on("click",...
```

to

```
$("body").unbind('click').on("click",
```

Hope this help!